# Laravel Gate code not being called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My Gate function doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code for calling the gate:

```
if(Gate::denies('has-system-access')){
    return view('auth.login')->with('noAccess', true);
}
```

and here's the gate definition:

```
Gate::define('has-system-access', function($user){
    $access = AccessMatrix::join('tjsg_hris.department_details AS dd', 'ltxx_systemadmin.access_matrix_department.department_id', '=', 'dd.department_id')
        ->join('tjsg_hris.employee_details as ed', 'dd.department_id', '=', 'ed.department_id')
        ->join('ltxx_systemadmin.system_details AS sd', 'access_matrix_department.system_id', '=', 'sd.id')
        ->where([
            'sd.system_code'=>'hris',
            'access_matrix_department.hasAccess'=>"1",
            'access_matrix_department.department_id'=>\DB::raw('ed.department_id'),
            'ed.employee_id'=>$user->employee_id
        ])->first();

    if($access){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

I tried commenting all the code on the gate definition and adding return true; but still doesn't work.

Comment: You should add `return false` to check it since `denies` means there is no access.

Comment: Tried that too but still doesn't work.

Comment: try to `dd` anything inside the Gate closure to see if the function is actually being ran.

Comment: doesn't dump anything, I've no idea why.